# iOS: Overlay(Mix) two video files using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, overlay, avasset, mov

I want to **overlay(mix)** two video files.

I am using AVAssetExportSession to overlay(mix) video files but it is not working.

When I try to overlay(mix) one .mp4 and one .mov video file,
It is giving an error,

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11841 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The video could not be composed., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001f03690 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17390 "(null)"}}
```

When I try to overlay(mix) two .mov video files,
It is giving an error,

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c65080 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}}
```

Comment: The reason is obvious `This media format is not supported`, isn't it?

Comment: Add some code to explain what you have done so far for this issue, also it will help others to replicate the issue.